# Copy one entire columns data from excel and paste in Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have implemented Add new column for all rows and remove column in kendo grid with below reference

```
http://jsbin.com/oBeHAWuJ/1/edit
```

And my requirement is Copy one entire  columns data from excel and paste in Kendo grid. Its should paste in one new entire column.

When click the Add column- I am creatig empty column. Using **batch : true** i am editing that specified column. So How can we achive this. Please any help. Is there any other way for adding columns , removing column and Copy one entire columns data from excel and paste in Kendo grid.

Here is the modified Code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {

                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataSource: dataSource,
                batch: true,
                editable: true,
                columns: $scope.gridColumns,

            };
```